# VBA reference to a table in different worksheet

Tags: excel, external, definition, vba

I'm trying to use vlookup in VBA.

1. Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls",    Title:="Please select a file")
2. Table1 = Sheet1.Range("A3:A7000") ' SiteID
3. Table2 = [Filename]Sheet1.Range("A3:I13")
4. Roww = Sheet1.Range("E2").Row
5. Coll = Sheet1.Range("E2").Column
6. For Each cl In Table1
7. Sheet1.Cells(Roww, Coll) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, Table2, 1, False)
8. Roww = Roww +1
9. Next cl

My question is how do I define the table located in different worksheet/file on line 3?

Comment: `Workbooks("Filename").Sheets("Sheetname").Range("Range")`, filling in for your respective wb,ws, and range should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the workbook, worksheet and range to objects in VBA and refer to them by name..

example:

```
Sub test()

Dim filename As String
Dim fullRangeString As String

Dim returnValue As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim rng As Range

    'get workbook path
    filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls", Title:="Please select a file")


    'set our workbook and open it
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(filename)

    'set our worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'set the range for vlookup
    Set rng = ws.Range("A3:I13")


    'Do what you need to here with the range (will get error (unable to get vlookup property of worksheet) if value doesn't exist
    returnValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("test4", rng, 2, False)


    MsgBox returnValue
    'If you need a fully declared range string for use in a vlookup formula, then
    'you'll need something like this (this won't work if there is any spaces or special
    'charactors in the sheet name



    'fullRangeString = "[" & rng.Parent.Parent.Name & "]" _
                        & rng.Parent.Name & "!" & rng.Address

    'Sheet1.Cells(10, 10).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A1," & fullRangeString & ",8,False)"




    'close workbook if you need to
    wb.Close False


End Sub
```

Comment: thanx a lot for reply, tried your suggestion having used it with the line Sheet1.Cells(X,Y).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-4], rng, 10, False)". Macro is executing without error, however, when checking cell X,Y I can see "=VLOOKUP(A3, rng, 10, FALSE)" in the content and shell is showing #NAME?. Do you know what the problem can be?

Comment: I meant shouldn't I see the real range instead of rng variable in the formula?

Comment: @taiko if you're using your range string like that (rather than the way you first asked `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(` then you'll need to use a string similar to `fullRangeString` (see my edit). this will probably fail if you have spaces in your worksheets name (as they need enclosing with '' for the range to work properly in that case)

Comment: Ooouh, I see what you mean. Sorry for confusion, I used initially "Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup", but this gave me an error "Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class", so I tried diofferent approach, which apparetntly doesn't work either :(.  Ihave updated my initial question, so its more clear, what I want to achieve

Comment: @taiko I've updated. This will look for the value you specify ("test4" in my case) in the sheet you specify and return back the value that it finds in column B next to it. You will get an error if the value doesn't exist. (unable to get the VLOOKUP ......

Comment: Thank you very much for help. Your last idea (of course not only the last :) ) did it for me. The error was indeed caused by lookup value not existing in the lookup range. I searched little bit more and rectified it with adding "On Error Resume Next" to the Macro. Now it works fine. thanx a lot again

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
Sub vLook()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim Range1, myValue
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Code\Book4.xlsx")

Range1 = wb2.Sheets(1).Range("A1:C5")
myValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("Test", Range1, 2, False)

End Sub
```